# facebook - create/edit application remotely

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I was wondering if it was possible to create/edit a facebook application with the FB api.

This is related to creating custom pages for Fan pages.

I would like to be able to automatically create and edit applications from a backend and then push it to Facebook, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph api has the [Application](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) object but it says there in the doc:

> To create, administer or delete applications developers must go to the
>   Developer Application.

The api does however give you the ability to add/change some fields/connections the application object has.